# PHP: Alternative to putting "use Special\Library\SpecificClass" on top of each file

Tags: php, namespaces

Let's say I included a library that has a class, with important constants. To access these constants I could:

1.) Either use "use"

```
use Special\Library\SpecificClass as SpecificClass;
$value = SpecificClass::MY_CONSTANT;
```

2.) Alternatively I can put the full path:

```
$value = Special\Library\SpecificClass::MY_CONSTANT;
```

But I am using this "SpecificClass" in hundreds of php files, so I like to **define once that "SpecificClass" is by default "Special\Library\SpecificClass"**.

How can I do that?

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. If you use a decent IDE this aliasing is practically automatic. If you're not, it's a tiny bit of copy and paste.

Comment: I'd advise against doing anything that causes to `SpecificClass` be a reference to `Special\Library\SpecificClass` by magic.  It will only lead to confusion in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`class_alias()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) for that:

```
class_alias('Special\Library\SpecificClass', 'SomeClass');
```

Now you can access the class from the root namespace with:

```
SomeClass::MY_CONSTANT;
```

and if you are going to use it under a namespace:

```
use \SomeClass;
```

> **Note:** Just make sure that you're using this with caution. It *will* make it harder to follow the code if you run into issues, since you then must know that it is an alias and where that alias was set. It's kind of an anti-pattern, if you ask me.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. I feel like a total noob for not knowing that, even though I developed several years with PHP. Thanks a lot, Magnus.

Comment: @PascalKlein - No probs. Just want to note that it will make it harder to follow the code if you run into issues. Then you must know that it is an alias and where the alias is set. And feel free to mark the answer, if it works for you.